# Rewrite the following code to have the arithmetic performed only once, even if the loop executes 1,000 times?

Tags: java

So I'm reading a programming book and it had this question written:

> How could you rewrite the following code to have the arithmetic
>   performed only once, even if the loop executes 1,000 times?
>
> `while (x < a + b)`
>    `// loop body`

The correct answer is this:

```
int sum = a + b;
while(x < sum)
// loop body
```

I'm really not understanding the logic here....Can someone explain this answer to me? Because this doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: What part do you not understand?

Comment: You mean you believe that the optimizer will have the runtime do `a + b` only once for `while (x < a + b)`?

Comment: What happens in the loop body? Presumably `x` must be changed or the loop will run forever, or not at all. Are `a` and `b` unchanged in the body?

Comment: I got it now! Huge brain fart :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version of the loop:

```
while (x < a + b)
// loop body
```

The sum `a + b` is calculated during *each* iteration of the loop.  If the sum is independent of the loop and never changes, then this is wasteful.  So one option for efficiency is to compute this sum *outside* the loop as in the second version:

```
int sum = a + b;
while(x < sum)
// loop body
```

I would expect that a good Java or C compiler would be able to detect this on its own, and make this optimization automatically.

Comment: Ah, I got it. This makes sense now. Honestly, I think I confused myself- such a simple concept. For some reason I thought I had to find a way to make the loop only iterate ONE time. I guess these long hours of studying is crippling my brain :P

Comment: Yes when I first glanced at your question this is what I was expecting too.  However, such a question is also possible if the loop is doing something in the body which also could be done just once outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the while condition (`x < a + b`) is tested every time the loop runs.  This causes the program to calculate a + b every time the condition is tested.  In the second example, a + b is calculated before the while loop is executed so the condition test doesn't have to do it every time.

Assumption: neither a nor b are modified in the loop body